Pom File Setup - things to remember for spring boot
What are the key things to remember about the Pom file in a spring boot application?
this is what the empty pom looks like.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>za.ac.cput</groupId>
    <artifactId>ADP-June-prep</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>



use start.spring.io.


To add spring to your already existing pom, you need to set the parent pom and the additional spring-dependencies you want to use.
Put this part in your pom to add the spring-parent pom:
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>

Add the dependencies you require. Example:
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

You don't need a version for the spring-dependencies, because it is managed by the parent-pom.

Always remember the parent...
note: its goes below the project & modelVersion tags.
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.5</version>
</parent>

<groupId>za.ac.cput</groupId>
<artifactId>ADP-June-prep</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


It doesn't need to be in a specific place, just in the pom.
